# DIFx: MsiProcessDrivers, WdfPostDeviceRemove and scheduling

Tags: wix, windows-installer, driver

I'm writing an installer for a WDF driver, and am finding that 
MsiProcessDrivers is being run after files have been removed. The 
problem is that according to the documentation, I need to run 
WdfPostDeviceRemove() after the service has been deleted - which 
requires WdfCoInstaller01009.dll to be loaded. Since that's already been 
deleted, my custom action is failing.  Should I be scheduling 
MsiProcessDrivers earlier in the InstallExecute sequence, or do people 
just avoid DIFx and use DPinst etc. for drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that your driver depends on a file installed by the package.

The recommended approach would be to make the DLL dependency a temporary file. Here is an article with more details: http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-environment/temporary-files

Basically, the DLL can be stored in [Binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) table and extracted during install or uninstall.